# Bootstrap 3 Modal Will not Display Modal Title or Input Labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm customizing a bootstrap template for a friend's church. Just something simple so they have a web presence. I'm creating a contact form, and I want it to be a modal where the user enters their info then sends off their comment.  However, the issue I'm having is that the modal will not display the modal-title or labels for the inputs. I'm totally confused, because I actually copied the exact same code from a previous web-page I built with bootstrap. I modified only a few things (took away some input groups and changed titles, etc), but nothing that should be affecting the functionality.

Here is a link to the functioning one: www.rawgit.com/znagatani/schedule_me/master/index.html .

Here's the markup for that modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="cta" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sign-up">Let's Go!</button>
<div class="modal" id="sign-up">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control modal-sign" placeholder="Goku" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control modal-sign" placeholder="Son" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="text">Valid Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control modal-sign" placeholder="kakarot7z@example.com" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control modal-sign" placeholder="ssjssgWarrior" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control modal-sign" placeholder="kamehamehax10" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Create Account</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then here's a link to the one for the church: www.rawgit.com/znagatani/cross_bootstrap/contact-modal/index.html

And here's the markup:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-contact btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-us">Contact Us</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="contact-us">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group contact-input">
                    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control modal-sign" placeholder="John" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group contact-input">
                    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control modal-sign" placeholder="Doe" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group contact-input">
                    <label for="text">Valid Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control modal-sign" placeholder="example@example.com" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="What's your question, comment, or concern?"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Send it!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that the first one displays the labels and title correctly; the second doesn't. Why is this?? If the answer isn't something glaringly obvious in the modal markup, then maybe the template is overriding bootstrap's javascript.

And I'm sorry if this question has been asked already... I searched around and did not find anything that answered this specific question. Thank you so much!

Comment: in 2nd HTML modal, the labels does exist in modal but the color of text is white as like background color at this link www.rawgit.com/znagatani/cross_bootstrap/contact-modal/index.html

Comment: As Shehary stated, the color is white. Using `<h4 class="modal-title" style="color:red;">Sign Up</h4>` shows the text. There is also other text on your page you are not seeing due to the color being white.

Comment: @Zach Nagatani also check for jQuery and bootstrap JS libraries, you have them in header and so as in footer too, remove both lib from either header or footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style to your custom css file:

```
.modal-content {
    color: #000;
}
```

This will change the `font-color` of the label and heading of your modal to black.

Comment: WOW. I had thought of this, too, but figured I could tell if that was the problem by highlighting the text with my mouse... which I couldn't do. Thank you; this obviously worked!